# How to include the contents of a markdown page into a post with Jekyll?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll

I am pretty new to websites with Jekyll hosted on Github, and I was wondering if there was a neat way to include the contents of a markdown page (say [this one](https://github.com/studio-dessai/playlists/blob/master/2014.06.05.md)) into a post (say [this one](https://github.com/studio-dessai/studio-dessai.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-06-05-sdi.MARKDOWN)) in order to always have the contents up to date if the source page is modified?

Answer (score 2):

[Breno Salgado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586033/breno-salgado) posted [this simple Jekyll plugin on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226076/in-jekyll-is-there-a-concise-way-to-render-a-markdown-partial):

**./_plugins/markdown_tag.rb**:

```
module Jekyll
  class MarkdownTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text.strip
    end
    require "kramdown"
    def render(context)
      "#{Kramdown::Document.new(File.read(File.join(Dir.pwd, '_includes', @text))).to_html}"
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('markdown', Jekyll::MarkdownTag)
```

According to [this page](http://wolfslittlestore.be/2013/10/rendering-markdown-in-jekyll/) you should be able to use code like this:

```
{% markdown test.md %}
```

To render the contents of the markdown file.

Comment: Great, thank you for that, I managed to set it up. However, because the files I want to include are in a different repo (but same project), how do I tell Jekyll to look for them there (and not just in '_includes'), without having to create a submodule?

Comment: At the end, it is not possible to use a custom plugin on GitHub Pages because they override parts of _config.yml to always enable the Jekyll safe mode (and therefore only allow the few plugins supported by GitHub). I will have to find a different solution...